# Accessing variable from file pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have one `variable.list` file. All variables are defined here, like:

```
Tablename="emp"
Dbname="hr"
```

Now I want access all these variables from `main.py` script.

I have seen some thread on this where it is suggested to do following.

```
From variable.list import *
```

But it is throwing error that `variable.list` not defined.

> No module name variable.list

Where to keep `variable.list` file? How to import all the variables?

Answer (score 0):

When you write import variables.list python searching for variables module not a file. You can rename your file as variables.py then try

```
import variables
```